# How to get the latest inserted identity from a table?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to retrieve the latest inserted or even updated identity from a table. But whenever I write the following code there is no results at all.

```
select * 
from PersonHowEducation prh 
inner join HowzeEducation he on prh.HowzeEducationId = he.HowzeEducationId
where he.HowzeEducationId = @@IDENTITY
```

What shall I really do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were part of a batch script, and you have only just inserted it in the same session, then you would use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to retrieve the last inserted `HowzeEducationId` value.

```
select * from PersonHowEducation prh inner join HowzeEducation he on 
      prh.HowzeEducationId=he.HowzeEducationId
      where he.HowzeEducationId=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

However, if this is from a completely different session, one that DID NOT **JUST** perform the insert, then you can get the last record inserted using

```
select * from PersonHowEducation prh inner join HowzeEducation he on 
      prh.HowzeEducationId=he.HowzeEducationId
      where he.HowzeEducationId=(select top(1) HowzeEducationId from HowzeEducation
                                 order by HowzeEducationId desc)
```

*Note: There could be rare cases where an identity insert does **not** create the largest id in the table, for example if someone decided a table should have 1 record of id= 1,000,000,001 and manually reseeded the identity back to 10,001.*

Another alternative, which may fizz if it is possible for the record to be deleted after insertion.

```
select * from PersonHowEducation prh inner join HowzeEducation he on 
      prh.HowzeEducationId=he.HowzeEducationId
      where he.HowzeEducationId=(SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('HowzeEducation'))
```

Comment: But sometimes someone that update his fields and the Id for that man is not in the last row (maybe in some other rows)so i want to find exactly that Updated HowzeEducationId. Is that possible?

Comment: I just gave you both scenarios. The first query is if the person himself did the update - get back using SCOPE_IDENTITY(). The other is for finding the last insert `by anyone`